# Media queries not working?

Tags: html, css

Am I doing something wrong? Basicly when someone is on a mobile version I want the top two gre tables to be full width heres a [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLutv389/)

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
      table[class="mobile_version"] {
      width:100%; !important;
      };
    };
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    td[class="mobile-hide"]{
      display: none !important;
    };
   };
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    td[class="mobile-show"]{
      display: inline !important;
      text-align: right;
    };
   };
```

HTML

```
<tr>
        <td>
          <table class="mobile_version" style="float:left;display: inline-block;background-color:#F2F2F2; color: #231F20;font-family:Arial; font-size: 15px;height:50%; padding: 10px 10px 40px 10px; text-align: left; width: 45%;Margin-right:3%;line-height: 168%;Margin-top:10px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <span>
                  <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Order #:</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;35644:</span></div> 
                  <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Ordered by:</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dan Utterwood</span></div> 
                  <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Paid by:</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Debit Card</span></div>
                  <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Expected Delivery:</span></div>
                  <div><span>14th December</span></div>
                  <div><span style= "font-weight:bold">Postage Method:</span></div>
                  <div><span>Airmail</span></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <table class= "mobile_version"style="float:left;display: inline-block; background-color:#F2F2F2; color: #231F20;font-family:Arial; font-size: 15px;height:50%; text-align: left;padding: 10px 10px 40px 10px; width: 45%;min-height:170px;Margin-top:10px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <div><span style= "font-weight:bold; line-height:170%">Ordered to:</span></div>
                  <div><span>Ross Kemp</span></div> 
                  <div><span>Space</span></div>
                  <div><span>Spacey Space</span></div> 
                  <div><span>Spacey space, space</span></div>
                  <div><span>SP4C5E</span></div>
                  <div><span>Spaaace</span></div>
                  <div><span style= "font-weight:bold; line-height:135%">Delivery Instructions:</span></div>
                  <div><span>Leave with neighbors cat<span></div>
                </div>
              </tr>
            </td>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I have already made it responsive as you can see with the inline: block however it just wont read the media queries

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

**UPDATED**

Ok so this is great I have the media queries in however since i've put them in i've had a few problems

1. The first set of blocks dont align on one line anymore and I cannot put a margin on the right hand side
2. Secondly I cannot seem to have two td.blahblah{afafsasdff}and they cancel eachother out

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/whxfhdcc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of problems with your css. First at all is better if you use the class selector `.` instead of the attribute selector `[attr]`. The semicolons are bad written. It's no need to put semicolon after every line break in CSS, only in the end of attributes.

You can view it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tLutv389/1/

That's your new css

```
  @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      table.mobile_version {
      width:100% !important;
      }
    td.mobile-hide{
      display: none !important;
    }
    td.mobile-show{
      display: table-cell !important;
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Whats the between using a Attr and a selector

Comment: if you have this html: `<tag class="one-class two-class">` and you use this css selector `tag[class="two-class"]` it doesn't work, because is a pair of key->value to match another selections. To select this tag the correct sentence will be `tag.one-class` or `tag.two-class` or  `tag.one-class.two-class`. It's basic CSS selectors with dot `.` for classes and hash `#` for ids.

Comment: You're welcome. I hard recommend to you to read a basic manual of CSS, you have more clear this questions. Good luck!

Comment: I edit my answer because you need in `td.mobile-show` to put `display:table-cell` to correctly render the cell. Inline value is for inline tags (`a, span, strong, em, etc`)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Change your css code

  @media screen and (max-width:480px){
          table[class="mobile_version"] {
          width:100% !important;//width:100%; !important; was wrong
          };
        };
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        td[class="mobile-hide"]{
          display: none !important;
        };
       };
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        td[class="mobile-show"]{
          display: inline !important;
          text-align: right;
        };
       };
```